# splitting a line into array in bash with tab as delimiter

Tags: bash, array

I have a file in the following format and it is tab separated

```
a   k   testis  adult   male    8 week  rRNA
b   k   testis  adult   male    8 week  rRNA
c   k   testis  adult   male    8 week  rRNA
```

I want to do some operation on each line so I am using a while loop.I want to split each line on tab and then store let's say 6th column which is `8 week` in a variable. I am using this code but I am not able to get what I want

```
while read -r line; do tmp=(${line///}); col6=${tmp[5]}; echo "$col6"; done < file.txt
```

This gives me `8` and not `8 week`. 8 week has a space in between 8 and week and hence I want to split the line on tab.

Comment: I suppose that you want to save each 6th field value into an array, not a variable, right?

Comment: the 6th field is 8 week. I want to save that in a variable

Comment: then, your title contradicts with your description. Update your question

Comment: I can't see what the contradiction is? They want to split the line, pick one of the fields and put it in a variable.

Comment: As a general rule, you really don't want to use the shell for text parsing. It is very hard to do correctly (as you're finding out) and will be *very* slow. Have a look at [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) for more details and [How can I extract/change lines in a text file whose data are separated into fields?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/210336) for other options.

Comment: @ilkkachu, read the entire question: the title is "splitting a line into **array** in bash with tab as delimiter" , the description says: "say 6th column which is 8 week in a **variable**"

Comment: @terdon: I actually have another column which is a URL. I want to use wget command on the URL and use the -O option to change the file name. I have been having issues where space and tab cause problems to me. So should I use awk for processing here?? Thanks for all your help

Comment: Sure, awk, cut, perl, *anything* but the shell is better. For instance, in awk, all you would need is `awk -F "\t" '{print $6, $7}'` to get the 6th and 7th columns. By the way, it looks like you might be interested in our new [bioinformatics.se] site. Come on over!

Comment: @terdon: Can I post this same question on the Bioinformatics site so that I can get some more clarifications from you or the community?

Comment: Please don't, no. Don't post identical questions on different Stack Exchange sites, that is called "cross-posting" and is against the rules. Either delete the question from one site and post on the other or adapt the question to fit the target site better. Posting a similar, but different, question is fine.

Comment: @terdon : I posted it on the bioinformatics site as a different question where I don't want to use shell for text parsing. Have a look and share your thoughts. Thanks again

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736202/read-tab-separated-file-line-into-array

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The array assignment `tmp=(${line///})` splits the value on whatever characters `IFS` contains, which by default includes tabs, *and spaces* and newlines. (I don't see what the empty substitution does.) To split only on tabs, set `IFS` to this:

```
foo=$'a\tk\testis\tadult\tmale\t8 week\tRNA'
IFS=$'\t'
tmp=($foo)
echo "${tmp[5]}"
```

Though that still leaves globbing as an issue, and since you are already using `while read`, you could use `read -a tmp` (in Bash only, replace `-a` with `-A` with ksh/zsh/yash), it splits the input line based on `IFS`, and stores the resulting fields as elements of the named array:

```
$ while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a tmp ; do
    echo "${tmp[5]}"
done <<< $'a\tk\testis\tadult\tmale\t8 week\tRNA'
```

That prints `8 week`. The other upside with this is that the change in `IFS` is only in effect for the duration of the `read`, not for the rest of the script.

Beware however that `read` strips empty fields when using tab as a delimiter. In `zsh`, you could replace `IFS=$'\t'` with `IFS=$'\t\t'` to stop that from happening.

Of course, if we know the number/meaning of the fields, we could just have `read` split them to separate named variables:

```
... IFS=$'\t' read -r col1 col2 col3 ...
```

Or, if you only want to print that one column, use `cut`:

```
cut -d$'\t' -f 6  < file.txt
```

If you have empty columns, `cut -d$'\t'` and `IFS=$'\t'` have different behaviour with regard to them. Cut will treat each individual tab as a distinct separator, while `read` will take consecutive tabs as just a *single* separator. That is, the string `foo<tab><tab>bar` will be read as just two columns by `read`, but three columns by `cut`.

You can't change this for tabs, but printing characters are always recognized as distinct separators, so you could change the tabs to some character that doesn't appear in the data, and then use that as the separator, e.g. `... | tr '\t' : | IFS=: read -r -a tmp` or so.

Comment: can you tell what -a tmp is doing??

Comment: @user3138373 the `-a` flag tells `read` to store what it reads as an array.

Comment: This will not work if you have mutliple consequent empty columns as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736202/read-tab-separated-file-line-into-array

Comment: @giorgio79, yes, you're right, because space and tab in `IFS` are treated differently from other characters (newline too, maybe, but it doesn't matter for `read` here). If there are empty columns (which there aren't in the question here), you'd need to do something like `... | tr '\t' : | IFS=: read -r -a tmp` to not have the separator be tab or space.

Comment: Thanks @ikkachu I went with a script meanwhile. For reference, I bumped into this issue with the geonames cities dump that is tab separated but has lots of empty cols.

Comment: @giorgio79, yep, it's a good point. Just didn't occur to me when writing that since the data in the question didn't have empty columns. I edited the answer to include that.

Comment: Does `IFS` play completely different roles?

Comment: @Dims, mmhh, can you clarify a bit? I think I'm too tired right now to pick up what you're asking.